# Making Cross Domain Ajax Requests

Tags: ajax, cors, same-origin-policy

Lets say, I have 2 web servers hosted at a.com and b.com b.com does NOT accept cross-domain requests from a.com.

IN one tab of my browser I have opened http://a.com and in another tab i have opened http://b.com.

As per Same Origin Policy, which of the following are true.

1) From http://a.com using ajax I can make cross-domain GET and POST request  to http://b.com but can not read the response from http://b.com

2) From http://a.com using ajax I can make cross-domain GET and POST request  to http://b.com and I can also read the response from http://b.com

3) From http://a.com using ajax I can make cross-domain GET, POST, PUT, DELETE request to http://b.com but can not read the response from http://b.com

4) From http://a.com using ajax I can make cross-domain GET, POST, PUT, DELETE request  to http://b.com as well as  read response from http://b.com

P.S. Not expecting any lectures on SOP and CORS. Short and sweet answers requested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only true answer is 1. Simply because CORS **preflight** request **fails** on 3 and 4, so the actual request never even takes place.